# Solidity, how can I import struct mapping in contract A from contract B?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

```
contract B {
  struct Player {
    uint id;
  } 
  mapping (uint=> Player) Players; 
}

contract A {
  constructor() public {
    B.Player storage p = B.Players[1];
  }
}
```

Report err at B.Players[1]:Member "Players" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract B).

So, how can I use mapping Players in A from B?

Comment: You cannot access private variables of other contracts. The variables need to be public if you want others to access them.

Comment: contract B {
  struct Player {
    uint id;
  } 
  mapping (uint=> Player) public Players; 
}

contract A {
  constructor() public {
    B.Player storage p = B.Players[1];
  }
}

Comment: its the same err

Comment: I think the issue here is that you're trying to access contract state, which is only possible when you're referring to an object of type B, not to the contract B itself. An analogy would be that the contract is like a blueprint for a house, and just as you cannot access the property "owner" for a blueprint, but only when you construct a house that an owner is accessible, similarly only when you have an object of type B, that you can access it's storage member variable Players[1] etc.

Answer (score 2):

> You can not directly access variables of other contracts. One of the
>   way that you have to inherit contract B for using its variable.

```
contract B {    
    struct  Player {
        uint id;   
    }
    mapping (uint=> Player) public Players; 
 }

contract A is B {
    constructor() public {
        B.Player storage p = B.Players[1];   
    }
 }
```

Comment: Inherit will make my code too long(over 1000 line) then out of gas.I'm finding the way that I can access variables in B contract.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface to use the datatype in both contracts

```
interface IPerson{
  struct Name{
     string firstName;
     string lastName;
  }

  
}

contract Admin{
   add(IPerson.Name name){
   
   }
}
```